# SQL Server Developer Edition 2014 installation failed

Tags: sql-server

I have downloaded the SQL Server Developer Edition 2014 "en_sql_server_2014_developer_edition_with_service_pack_1_x64_dvd_6668542.iso"
and extracted the iso file using Power iso.

After clicking Setup file am getting below error

**This SQL Server setup media does not support the language of the OS, or does not have the SQL Server English-language version installation files. Use the matching language-specific SQL Server media; or install both the language specific MUI and change the format and system locales through the regional settings in the control panel**

My windows7 os regional language is set to ENGLISH(US) .

I donn't know what may be cause for these.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear about whats wrong. Googling "SQL Server setup media does not support the language of the OS" returns results that indicate that your local variable is not the same as requested in the Setup. Maybe that iso is EN-GB.

You can check your registry for your language:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\Locale
```

You can also use powershell to check:

```
Get-WinUserLanguageList
```

And also powershell to change it e.g.:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US
```

Comment: I have checked language  . its currently set en-US only. but still am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I received the same error when I was trying to install MSSQL Server 2014 Express edition on my Windows VPS 2012. The VPS is created in Germany Datacenter. I had used the Firefox browser to download the SQL Server setup file. I fixed the issue by doing the following steps:

```
Step1: Uninstalled Firefox browser from the VPS.
Step2: Removed the Microsoft SQL Server folder from Program Files and Program Files (x86). Also removed the extracted folder of SQL Server from Download folder (SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU)
Step3: Rebooted the VPS
Step4: Downloaded the latest Google Chrome browser and installed it on VPS
Step5: Again download MSSQL Server 2014 express edition from Microsoft site.
Step6: Run the MSSQL setup file and configured it successfully.
```